# How to verify a text is present on a webpage for 'n' times

Tags: robotframework

I wanted to verify a text in a webpage exist for  2 times or ‘n’ times. I have used “**Page Should Contain**” keyword but it says “Pass” when it identifies single occurrence. I don’t want to verify using locator.

Ex: I want to verify the text "Success" is available in a current webpage for 3 times using robot framework

Any inputs/suggesstions would be helpful.

Comment: in browser, `document.body.innerHTML.match(/Success/g).length >= 3` should work.

Comment: Why don't you want to verify using a locator? That's purposefully making the problem much harder to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Too bad you don't want to use a locator, as robotframework has a keyword just for that:

```
Xpath Should Match X Times  //*[contains(., "Success")]  2
```

The caveat is the locator should not be prepended with `xpath=` - just straight expression.

The library keyword `Page Should Contain` does pretty much exactly that, by the way.

---

And if you want to find how many times the string is present in the page - easy:

```
${count}=  Get Matching Xpath Count  //*[contains(., "Success")]
```

And then do any kind of checks on the result, e.g.

```
Should Be Equal      ${count}      2
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought the problem of not using locator sounds fun (the rationale behind the requirement still unclear, yet), so another solution - look in the source yourself:

```
${source}=    Page Source     # you have the whole html of the page here
${matches}=   Get Regexp Matches    ${source}   >.*\b(Success)\b.*<
${count}=     Get Length    ${matches}
```

The first one gets the source, the second gets all non-overlapping (separate) occurrences of the target string, when it is (hopefully) inside a tag. The third line returns the count.

---

Disclaimer - please don't actually do that, unless you're 100% sure of the source and the structure. Use a locator.

Comment: Looking at the comments on the question, this was actually proposed by YOU (cool nickname) in javascript - well, here it is in RF syntax, with a more fancy regex :)